# How to retrieve exit status from ruby Open3.popen3()?

Tags: ruby, popen3

I seem to be stuck trying to retrieve the exit status of a shell command which was started from ruby's Open3.popen3()-method.

Here's my code:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('ls')
```

When I now try to access `$?` it still is `nil`

Is it possible to retrieve the exit status after all?

Notes:
- `ls` is not the command I'm trying to use in my script. I just used this to give an example. My script is a bit more complex and contains user input, which is why I need the sanitizing functionality of Open3.
- I've also tried the block variant of popen3, but didn't succeed with that either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`popen3` yields/returns four parameters, `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and `wait_thr`. `wait_thr` contains a method `wait_thr.value` which returns the exit status of the command (in fact, it is a `Process::Status` object according to documentation). Also have a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3

Comment: I knew that open3 also returns a thread but didn't know how to get its exit code. `wait_thr.value.success?` works like a charm, thank you very much!

Answer (score 34):

The concise answer is to use the 4th parameter of open3: `wait_thr`

- get whether any error is indicated: `wait_thr.value.success?`
- get the actual error level: `wait_thr.value.exitstatus`

Sample:

```
Open3.popen3(command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  return_value = wait_thr.value
end
puts "Error level was: #{return_value.exitstatus}" unless return_value.success?
```

Comment: Up voted this answer because it provides a code example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need (standard output, error and exit code) in three lines:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("sleep 5; ls")
puts "#{stdout.read} #{stderr.read} #{wait_thr.value.exitstatus}"
```